# Is it proper to use `__mul__` etc in polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

In Pandas I frequently use methods like `a.add(b).mul(c).rename('xyz')` to chain different series computations. I find that these methods are not public in Polars, but I can do similar things by `df.select(pl.col(a).__add__(pl.col(b)).__mul__(pl.col(c)).alias('xyz')`.  I find this makes it much easier than using a lot of parentheses and much less error prone. Is this proper use though?

Comment: If the class defines `__add__()` and similar math operations, then the intended and normal way to use them would be via ordinary math operators: `(pl.col(a) + pl.col(b)) * pl.col(c)`.  Generally speaking, you *never* explicitly call a double-underscored method, except in a subclass to invoke the parent class implementation.

Comment: Thanks @jasonharper , I also feel it's unnormal, but super convenient. Like I can just chain `.alias('xyz')` without wrapping another parenthesis `((pl.col(a) + pl.col(b)) * pl.col(c)).alias('xyz')`. Sometimes I just forgot to wrap it and left it as `(pl.col(a) + pl.col(b)) * pl.col(c).alias('xyz')` , it would run but induce implicit bugs since the column has not been properly renamed as `xyz`.. Kind of curious why these methods aren't exposed as public, which Pandas does

Comment: this might be a reasonable feature request

Comment: There are a few discussions on the tracker: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/4224 With regards to the `.alias()` example - named args are allowed now, similar to `.assign()` in pandas which may be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is now supported as of version `0.20`, full list of operations [there](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/7660)

```
import polars as pl
df = polars.DataFrame({'a': [1,2], 'b': [2,5]})

df.select(pl.col('a').mul(2).add(3.14))
>>>
shape: (2, 1)
┌────────┐
│ a      │
│ ---    │
│ f64    │
╞════════╡
│ 5.1415 │
│ 7.1415 │
└────────┘
```